# Reading daily time-series using pandas and re-sampling to monthly

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python. I usually use `scikits.timeseries` to process time-series data. Now I would like to use `Panda` such as `read_csv` to do the same as the code shown below. I used the read_csv manual to read the file, but I don't know how to convert the daily time-series to monthly time-series.

The input is one column daily data starting from 2002-01-01 to 2011-12-31, so the length is 3652. The output will be one column monthly data starting from 2002-01 to 2011-12, so the length is 120.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scikits.timeseries as ts
stgSim = ts.time_series(np.loadtxt('examp.txt', delimiter = ',' , skiprows  = 1    ,
                                                       usecols   = [37] ),
                                            start_date ='2002-01-01',
                                            freq='d'                     )

v4 = ts.time_series(np.random.rand(3652),start_date='2002-01-01',freq='d')                              
startD = stgSim.date_to_index(v4.start_date) 
stgSim = stgSim[startD:]
stgSimAnMonth = stgSim.convert(freq='m',func=np.ma.mean)
```

Comment: Could you post the output?

Comment: @Wade I edited the question to explain the input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for `resample` which converts daily data to monthly data?

Say

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)    # set a random seed so that result is repeatable
ts = pd.Series(data=rng.rand(100),
               index=pd.date_range('2018/01/01', periods=100, freq='D'))
mts = ts.resample('M').mean()      # resample (convert) to monthly data
```

`ts` is like

```
2018-01-01    0.374540
2018-01-02    0.950714
2018-01-03    0.731994
...
2018-04-08    0.427541
2018-04-09    0.025419
2018-04-10    0.107891
```

Now you should have `mts` like

```
2018-01-31    0.444047
2018-02-28    0.498545
2018-03-31    0.477100
2018-04-30    0.450325
```

Comment: mts is not giving monthly value instead it gives one value.

Comment: `mts` should have 4 values, i.e. values for Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr 2018.